# How to check Socket server start or close on hosted server

Tags: php, sockets

i have done program using socket server in php it's working well on my localhost using command "php -q path-server-php.
I have upload all files on my hosted server (Paralles Panel) here i am unable to check socket server start or not ,please any one can help me how to check socket server is start or close, if it is close then it's start automatically using php script.

Comment: try to post sample server.php and client.php codes

Answer (score 1):

From [socket_read():](http://php.net/socket%5Fread)

socket_read() returns the data as a string on success, or FALSE on error (including if the remote host has closed the connection). The error code can be retrieved with socket_last_error(). This code may be passed to socket_strerror() to get a textual representation of the error.